# AWK command with gsub

Tags: awk

I got a file named test with below content

```
wenotnotfoo1txt     
iwiwiw     
ieieie     
wenotnotfoo2txt    
iwiwiw     
ieieie     
wenotnotfoo3txt     
iwiwiw     
ieieie

awk '{if(gsub(/txt/,"")){name=$0;}else{print > name}}' test
```

Use above awk command, I am able to generate below files.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     14 Feb  4 17:24 wenotnotfoo1     
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     14 Feb  4 17:24 wenotnotfoo2     
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     14 Feb  4 17:24 wenotnotfoo3

[root@localhost tmp]# cat wenotnotfoo1        
iwiwiw     
ieieie     
[root@localhost tmp]# cat wenotnotfoo2     
iwiwiw     
ieieie     
[root@localhost tmp]# cat wenotnotfoo3     
iwiwiw    
ieieie
```

I am happy with the content in each file generated.
But I want the file name to be generated as below.
Any idea?

```
foo1     
foo2     
foo3
```

Notes: foo1 instead of wenotnotfoo1 and so on, thanks in advance.

Comment: After removing txt in the content, is there a way to use the last 4 characters in the same line as file name?

Comment: Please try to mention your requirement/question in a single post itself. Try my code once and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: The first code is actually works but does not meet the requirement to use last 4 charaters in the same line for file name. For example ,  remove txt from "wenotnotfoo1txt " will become "wenotnotfoo1". I need to generate the file using last 4 characters which is foo1.  The second code got error as below awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=test FNR=1) fatal: function `ubstr' not defined

Comment: Sorry that my previous sample content was not good enough. See the new content here.  Sorry for the trouble.                                                              wenotnotfoo1txt     
iwiwiw     
ieieie     
wenotnotbor2txt    
iwiwiw     
ieieie     
wenotnotcto3txt     
iwiwiw     
ieieie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'sub(/txt$/,""){ close(f); f=substr($0,length($0)-3); next } {print > f}' test
```

Comment: It works.  Initially my file name end with ?  After research seems it was encoding issue. I use the vim to create the file and run the awk command again .Issue resolved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Appreciate if you can explain the 3 statements.

Comment: I actually think it's very self-explanatory - do you have any specific questions?